# Exit shell scripts when previously finished child has failed

Tags: bash, shell, sh, wait, exit

I have a shell script that executes several sub scripts in the background using `&` and some scripts by just calling them with `./`
This all happens in a loop in the parent script.

At at the end of the loop in the parent script i want to wait until all child processes are finished and get their exit status. If one of the child scripts has failed I want to exit the loop and the parent script.

What i currently do is after each subscript is executed i collect its pid using `$!`. Then i loop through the pids and call `wait $pid || exit 1`.

But for some reason i get the error: `pid 12345 is not a child of this shell`. What could be the reason for this error?

Is there another way to do this?

**EDIT:**

```
pids=""

extract () {
./p1.sh &
pids="$pids $!"

./p2.sh &
pids="$pids $!"
}

load () {
./p3.sh
pids="$pids $!"
}

extract
load

echo ${pids[@]}

for p in $pids; do
    wait $p
done
```

The output is:

```
pid: 13725 end process 1
pid: 13726 end process 2
pid: 13727 end p3
13725 13726 13726
```

As you can see the pid 13726 is somehow added twice. The error message i get is: `wait: pid 13726 is not a child of this shell`

Comment: Most likely because the child process has ended

Comment: but i can do `echo abc; wait $!` and i don't get the error, so i assume that it also works for already finished processes?

Comment: `echo` is a shell builtin, it does not create a child process.  I don't know what process you are waiting on, but `$!` will be the PID of the previous external program you ran.

Comment: my question then would be can i use `wait` to get the exit status of a previously ended process or not?

Comment: Just looked at the source code.  If the job is still in the `jobs` list then it can be waited on, otherwise no.

Comment: Can you tell me how long it will be in the jobs list, or when it is evicted?

Comment: I think you can always wait for a child even if he has ended. Maybe it would be easier if you provide a sample code with some dummy calls? Something containing the spawn for, the way you store PIDs and the waiting for.

Comment: I have noticed, the problem is caused by a shell script i call with `./child.sh` If i execute a script like that, is it then not a child of the parent shell that executed it?

Comment: I added some code, to reproduce the error

Comment: In your example, did you notice that the job in `load()` function is not run in background?  No `&`, so the `$!` will be the *previous* background job, which is why the PIDs are repeated.

Comment: By the way, `echo ${pids[@]}` can be written as `echo "$pids"` since `pids` is not an array.

Comment: I thought `$!` adds the pid of the previously executed process to pids.
Does it mean then, the script in the load function is not executed in a subshell?

Comment: It is not executed in a subshell, it is executed in a child process (not the same thing).  Anyway, `$!` is only set by jobs set into the background, either using `&` or `bg` command.

Comment: I ran your test with the `&` added to `loads()` and an `echo $?` after the `wait()` in the loop.  I made `p1` exit 1, `p2` exit 2, `p3` exit 3 and the exit codes were correctly reported.

Comment: I know that, but the scripts that are executed in the load function should be executed in sequence. Thats why i dont use the `&`

Comment: If you don't run the commands in the load function asynchronously, then they are done when the function returns and there's nothing to wait for.  $! is still the pid of the last job you ran in the background, and you've already added that to your string (not an array) of pids.